# AngularJS directive not reacting to attribute change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I have a chat directive that I use to place a chatroom on the page.

```
mod.directive('chat', function () {
  return {
    templateUrl: '/chat',
    replace: true,
    scope: { 
      chatID:'@chat',
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $timeout) {
      var id = $scope.chatID
      ...
    },
    link: function ...
  }
})
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="chat" chat="{{currentChatID}}" ui-view="currentChat"></div>
<div class="content" ui-view="mainContent"></div>
```

This is in a file called "standard"

```
mod.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('standard', {
    views: {
      'main': {
        templateUrl: '/tmpl/standard',
        controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
          $scope.currentChatID = ''
          $scope.setCurrentChatID = function(newID) {
            $scope.currentChatID = newID
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
})
```

I'm using angularjs-ui-router to create a parent view with the chat directive providing a chat inside that view. This works fine on first page load, the chat loads up. But when I change the page/chat room, I use another controller to run `setCurrentChatID()`. This changes the `currentChatID` for the chat element in the DOM, I also see the chat element's properties change to the new ID in angularjs-batarang but the chat directive's controllers do not run. How do I get this to work properly / activate the chat's controllers when the chatID changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing the rest of your `chat` controller's code, but you may need a `$watch` inside your chat controller like:

```
$scope.$watch('chatID', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // run some code here whenever chatID changes
});
```

**EDIT:** For more about the `$digest` loop and Angular's runtime operations, see this [AngularJS Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime). (Check the Runtime section)

For more about controllers, see this [AngularJS: Understanding Controllers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller) guide.  Here are the key points relevant to your question:

Controllers should be used only to:

1. Set up the initial state of a scope object.
2. Add behavior to the scope object. (to include creating a `$watch`, etc.)

The `$digest` loop processes only:

1. the `$evalAsync` queue
2. the `$watch` list

Comment: I'm just wondering if the controller code is supposed to react on digest or if you need to manually set a watch for that. It makes sense if you need a watch.

Comment: Normally, the controller itself should run only once per route.  Any logic that you want to run on digest should be manually placed in a `$watch`.